# How can I make my images render in Material UI Cards for React+Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image

I'm currently trying to render images in Material UI's cards. For each card, I'm passing in props from information read in a constants.tsx file. Currently, the heading, description, and bodyHeader are all being properly read, but my imgSrc is not.

My directory looks like this: 
[image]

And the snippet of my code displaying the card in my card.tsx looks like this:

```
export default function SimpleCard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const {title, bodyHeader, description, imgSrc} = props;
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardHeader 
            className = {classes.headerStyle}
            title={title}
      />
      <CardMedia
        style = {{height: '150px'}}
        //className={classes.media}
        image={imgSrc}
      />
```

And here is my constants.tsx

```
export default[
    {
        title: 'Finding Pitbulls Homes Through a Fun-Friendly Fostering Form',
        description: 'UX + UI Design',
        bodyHeader: 'Biggies Bullies Redesign',
        imgSrc: './images/publicart.png'
    },

    {
        title: 'Improving Public Art Appreciation and Social Connectivity Through a Life-Sized Circuit',
        description: 'UX Research',
        bodyHeader: "The Human Circuit",
        imgSrc: './images/pitbull.png'
    },

    {
        title: 'Creating an Intuitive and Useful Workday System for Employees at a Creamery',
        description: 'Fullstack Development',
        bodyHeader: "The Amazing Creamery Workday System",
        imgSrc: './images/workday.png'
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [require](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-display-images-from-local-assets-images-folder-when-working-with-react-feb6c5dba526) or [import](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) the images in order to render them.

**Use below to fix your issue**.

```js
<CardMedia
        style = {{height: '150px'}}
        //className={classes.media}
        image={require(imgSrc)} //<------ like this
      />
```

Comment: thanks that seemed to do the trick to render. Now i'm encountering the issue of reading the file. If my constants.tsx file is in the src same folder as the images.tsx, how come something like imgSrc: './images/publicart.png' is not working?

Comment: Your card is in components and png is in images ..... so you have to go one level up (use double dot) then go to images folder.... Use this  `../images/publicart.png`

Comment: that makes sense, so I made that adjustment in my constant.tsx file, but it doesn't seem to be rendering. I've also tried importing `import constants from '../constants` but that hasn't seem to work either

Comment: i see... should be some minor path issue ... is it possible to put ur code in sandbox and share link?

Comment: there is no issue with the answer.. seems there is a bug in codesandbox regarding `require`... probably related to this issue https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2488 .... if you load ur code in local , it shd work .... anyway.. to make it work in codesandbox you have to import it ... so just import all files manually in `constants.ts` and everything should work ... i have already made it work for you ... here is the updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/matt-website-fix-tdqqz?file=/src/components/Card.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when passing the `image` property of MUI `CardMedia` as a prop. What I did to fix this issue is pass the image file name, as a prop inside backticks.

```js
<CardMedia
    component="img"
    height="200"
    image={require(`../images/${props.image}.jpg`)}
    alt={props.name} 
/>
```

The data which I pass to this card media component is as follows:

```js
services: [
    {
        name: "Salon Haircut and Blow Dry",
        image: "s1",
    },
    {
        name: "Fringe/ Neck Trim only",
        image: "s2",
    },
]
```

Further explanation:
My images are in the `../images` directory. image names are like `s1.jpg`, `s2.jpg`.
Full source code will be added to [this repository:](https://github.com/NirmalSankalana/express-salon-booking-system)

Hope this will be helpful for anyone who got this error:)